# Why does this instruction still compile?

Tags: java, arrays

Even though there does not exist a method of println that takes an array as an argument,the following instruction compiles without errors.
Why does this happen? I was expecting it not to compile

```
System.out.println(newArray());
```

Comment: because there is one that accepts an `Object`.

Comment: Everything is an `Object`.

Comment: have you tried to put a whitespace between `new` and  `Array()`?

Comment: The only way that wouldn't compile is if `newArray()` is a `void` method; any other return type is a subtype of `Object`, or, in the case of primitives, an overload of `println` exists.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [println](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28java.lang.Object%29) method that accepts `Object`. And according to [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html):

> In the Java programming language, arrays are objects

Answer (score 1):

See the [documentation for the `PrintStream.println(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(java.lang.Object)). (Code formatting added by me).

```
public void println(Object x)
```

> Prints an `Object` and then terminate the line. This method calls at first `String.valueOf(x)` to get the printed object's string value, then behaves as though it invokes `print(String)` and then `println()`.

As mentioned in the comments already, in Java everything is an `Object`. `Object` is known as the "root class" because all other classes extend it. Therefore you can pass anything to `println`.